# SQL Compact Database larger than configured size

Tags: windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to search a mobile SDF database in Windows Mobile 6.1 and the database is about 270MB. Whenever the program tries to read from the database I get this error:

> "The database file is larger than the configured size.
>   This settings takes effect on the first concurrent database connection only [Required Max Database Size (in MB; 0 if unknown) =0]"

I tried specifying the size in the connection string but I get an error as well:

```
public bool ConnectDB(string strDB, string strPassword)
{
    try
    {
        string siz= "300";
        string connStr = "Data Source = " + strDB + "; Size = " + siz + "; Password = " + strPassword + ";";
        ceConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connStr);
        ceConnection.Open();
        if (ceConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            return true;
    } catch () {}
}
```

I get `unknown connection option in connection string: Size`.

Please help .

Comment: 270MB for a mobile DB is rather insane! Try using `MaxDatabaseSize=2048`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use "Max database size" (in MB)

```
"Data Source = " + strDB + "; Max Database Size = " + siz
```

Answer (score 0):

270 MB is way to large for a mobile database. Have you tried compressing it? You can use the SqlCeEngine class. Try Shrink() or Compact()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.shrink.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.compact.aspx

Comment: It may not be to large. It depends on what it's being used for and how it's beign queried.