# Database doesn't work successfully

Tags: database, linq, windows-phone-8, size, windows-phone

I'm working on a program that use images and sound.
i capture an image by the mobile and convert it to binary and insert into a database, and recording a voice and insert that into isolated storage.

This message appears to me after inserting many photos into the database, after that, the database doesn't inserted more images.

the database is implemented as classes and i use LINQ to insert/retrieve.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601706/sql-compact-database-size-problem ?

Comment: i can't use it, in this type of database no connection string.

Comment: What type of database are you using? Windows Phone supports many.

Comment: that implemented using classes ..